# Exponential of Kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-exponential, kronecker-product

It is well known that the *Kronecker sum* of matrices $A$,$B$, defined by
 $A \oplus B = A \otimes I + I \otimes B$, 
satisfies the nice identity

$ \text{exp}(A \oplus B) = \text{exp} A  \otimes \text{exp} B . $

What does not seem to be often discussed is the behavior of $\text{exp}(A \otimes B)$.

I am interested mostly in the case when $A,B$ are Hermitian. I suppose this is easy in certain special cases (e.g. when $A^2 = I$ and $B^2 = I$, the infinite series can be simplified) but surely there must be something nice one can say more generally.

Comment: Consider the fact that there is not much we can say in the $1 \times 1$ case: $e^{ab}$ doesn't simplify in a particularly nice fashion. Notably, $(e^a)^b$ doesn't translate very well to the matrix case.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're interested in taking the exponential of a Kronecker product? Do you have an application in mind?

Comment: The specific problem I had in mind was the exponentiation of Kronecker products of Pauli matrices, which is addressed in Section VIII of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.5986.pdf

Comment: To elaborate on that last point, in the linked article, the authors determine the exponential $\text{exp}(i t Z \otimes Z)$ by finding a matrix $U$ which conjugates $Z \otimes Z$ to $I \otimes Z$.

Comment: I see.  In this case, the fact that $Z \otimes Z$ is similar to $I \otimes Z$ is a nice consequence of the fact that $Z$ has eigenvalues $\pm1$. I wonder if in general something nice can be said about $\exp(A \otimes A)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one general approach: suppose that we can diagonalize $A$.  That is, we have $A = VDV^*$ where $V$ is unitary and
$$
D = \lambda_1 I_{m_1} \dot+ \cdots \dot+ \lambda_k I_{m_k} := \pmatrix{\lambda_1 I_{m_1}\\ & \ddots \\ && \lambda_k I_{m_k}}.
$$
for some unitary $V$.  Here, $I_k$ denotes the identity matrix of size $k$. Note that throughout, I use $\dot+$ to refer to the "diagonal sum"
$$
A \dot+ B = \pmatrix{A&0\\0&B}.
$$
We can now state that
$$
A \otimes B = (VDV^*) \otimes B = (V \otimes I_n)(D \otimes B)(V \otimes I_n)^*.
$$
where $n$ is the size of $B$. Now, assuming that we can compute $\exp(tB)$ easily, we can now compute
$$
\exp(D\otimes B) = \exp[(I_{m_1} \otimes (\lambda_{m_1}B)) \dot{+} \cdots \dot + (I_{m_k} \otimes (\lambda_{m_k}B))]\\
= (I_{m_1} \otimes \exp(\lambda_{m_1}B)) \dot{+} \cdots \dot + (I_{m_k} \otimes \exp(\lambda_{m_k}B)).
$$
With the above computed, we can now say that
$$
\exp(A\otimes B) = (V \otimes I_n)\exp(D\otimes B)(V \otimes I_n)^*.
$$

(Edited)

Comment: That final line doesn't make sense. You're missing an exp() function on the RHS.

Comment: @greg fixed it, thanks